# How to migrate a database from Odoo 9 to Odoo 11?

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-11

I would like to migrate data from Odoo 9 community to Odoo 11 community. So I want to write some migration scripts. But, currently I have no idea how I can write a migration script like [OpenUpgrade](https://doc.therp.nl/openupgrade/).

- **How I can use PostreSQL to migrate data from Odoo 9 to Odoo 11.**
- **Can I migrate data by connecting OdooRPC of both versions?**

If anyone have idea where to start then please share your ideas.

Comment: If I were you I would make the migration as easier as possible exporting only the main tables (customers, products, ...) and reimport them on Odoo 11

Comment: what about the remaining data lol @ChesuCR

Comment: That's no so important haha, you can always check the old data on the old Odoo intance. Migrate data is too costly

Comment: Anyway if you want to make sql or python scripts to migrate date you will need to know Odoo very well. Firts you will need to upgrade Odoo 9 to the latest commit. I will write for you into an answer...

Comment: I have idea about odoo development so please share your idea Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can migrate data in several ways. But you need to know Odoo very well to make such migration.

- **Raw SQL scripts**. If you are an SQL expert this could be a good way to map fields. Take into account that depending on your installed modules Odoo could use up to 500 tables or even more.
- **ETL tools such as Pentaho Kettle**. This is a costly way as well, but it has a GUI.
- **Openupgrade**. It offers migrations script (python) for the main Odoo modules. You would have to write your own migrations scripts for your custom modules and third parties modules (if they do not have them). You would need to follow these steps:

  1. Update the instance of Odoo 9.0 al to the latest commit
  2. Migrate your custom modules (source code) to the version 10.0, and then to the 11.0 version
  3. Analise the database changes of these modules to make the migration scripts (to store it in the `migrations` folder) to update the database structure from the version 9.0 to the 10.0 and to the version and 11.0. You can check examples of these kind of scripts in the [Openupgrade project](https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade/tree/10.0/addons/account/migrations/10.0.1.1), they execute SQL code very often.
  4. Migrate the database with Openupgrade to the 10.0 version solving all the conflicts
  5. Migrate the database with Openupgrade to the 11.0 version

However, I have never made a complete migration using these methods because they are very costly. So my recommendation is to migrate the database partially, only the essential data (if you want a stable installation). You can even work with csv files, exporting those tables and reimporting them into the new database.

Comment: OpenUpgrade script works perfectly fine for the base modules. For custom modules you can write your own scripts.

Comment: It is all about the tables that are changing their names from one version to the other. If you are good with scripting maybe you should join OCA Devs and write some stuff for OpenMigrate?

If you are new to the stuff I would recommend to migrate the Odoo with only original modules and then upgrade the custom modules(or download versions for latest Odoo). 
I made tutorial for this:
https://cier.tech/blog/blog-1/post/how-to-upgrade-odoo-with-automated-migration-script-15

Comment: @PiotrCierkosz  When i tried to use OpenUpgrade  it replied Could not upgrade to version 10.0 So Only option left for me is RPC. Because i don't have ability to use raw Sql create kind of ETL Tool .  Thanks